# installing with NPM gives out error:2406C06E:random number generator

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using Ubuntu server 18.04.
Every time I try to use NPM it crashes and shows the following exception:

```
internal/crypto/random.js:119
   if (ex) throw ex;
       ^
Error: error:2406C06E:random number generator:RAND_DRBG_instantiate:error retrieving entropy
at Object.randomBytes (internal/crypto/random.js:54:31)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:444:32
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:496:3)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:28:13 {
  opensslErrorStack: [
  'error:2406B072:random number generator:RAND_DRBG_generate:in error state',
  'error:2406C06E:random number generator:RAND_DRBG_instantiate:error retrieving entropy',
  'error:2406B072:random number generator:RAND_DRBG_generate:in error state',
  'error:2406C06E:random number generator:RAND_DRBG_instantiate:error retrieving entropy'
 ]
}
```

Does anybody has any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: What you're trying to do? Installing any packages ?

Comment: I'm trying to install angular

Comment: What command have you tried ?

Comment: I tried with npm install -g @angular/cli
but the problem is that I can't use npm, every time I use it it throws the error, even when I want to see the version of npm installed with the npm -v command it also throws the same error

Comment: Could you please reinstall the node and npm ?

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya unfortunately it doesn't help. It seems to be a problem independent from nodejs version